# H10 App Crashed error when deploying node.js web app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-deployment, heroku-cli

I'm trying to deploy my node.js web app on Heroku but I keep getting an "App Crashed" error. I've tried all solutions that I've found on the internet but none seem to work. The logs are below:

```
heroku logs --tail
2020-12-16T20:31:26.148157+00:00 app[api]: Release v23 created by user <myemail>@gmail.com
2020-12-16T20:31:26.148157+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f6c6d04d by user <myemail>@gmail.com
2020-12-16T20:31:26.468824+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-16T20:31:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-12-16T20:31:50.479221+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-12-16T20:31:54.351123+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T20:31:54.351140+00:00 app[web.1]: > social-media-app@0.1.0 start /app
2020-12-16T20:31:54.351141+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-12-16T20:31:54.351141+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T20:32:00.964824+00:00 app[web.1]: �� ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.19.71.206/
2020-12-16T20:32:00.965313+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-12-16T20:32:00.965424+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-12-16T20:32:00.965521+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-12-16T20:32:00.965744+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-12-16T20:32:00.965746+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T20:32:01.091871+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-16T20:32:01.137571+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-16T20:32:01.141435+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-16T20:32:21.012471+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-12-16T20:32:24.057205+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T20:32:24.057227+00:00 app[web.1]: > social-media-app@0.1.0 start /app
2020-12-16T20:32:24.057227+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-12-16T20:32:24.057228+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T20:32:26.955003+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.16.214.14/
2020-12-16T20:32:26.955707+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-12-16T20:32:26.955832+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-12-16T20:32:26.955945+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-12-16T20:32:26.956218+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-12-16T20:32:26.956220+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T20:32:27.116530+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-16T20:32:27.180961+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-16T20:32:28.442226+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=college-social-media-app.herokuapp.com request_id=1d2de790-c63b-4741-b5f3-65cc99538550 fwd="98.217.113.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https   
2020-12-16T20:32:29.520392+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=college-social-media-app.herokuapp.com request_id=f17eb576-3131-4acd-8259-35c6ea119916 fwd="98.217.113.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-16T20:48:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user <myemail>@gmail.com
2020-12-16T20:50:27.826733+00:00 app[api]: Release v24 created by user <myemail>@gmail.com
2020-12-16T20:50:27.826733+00:00 app[api]: Deploy ca7fd011 by user <myemail>@gmail.com
2020-12-16T20:50:28.015378+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-16T20:50:36.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-12-16T20:50:39.641800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-12-16T20:50:44.110676+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T20:50:44.110733+00:00 app[web.1]: > social-media-app@0.1.0 start /app
2020-12-16T20:50:44.110738+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-12-16T20:50:44.110738+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-16T20:50:48.545375+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.216.142/
2020-12-16T20:50:48.546121+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-12-16T20:50:48.546385+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-12-16T20:50:48.546558+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-12-16T20:50:48.546939+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-12-16T20:50:48.546941+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T20:50:48.657160+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-16T20:50:48.705942+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-16T20:50:48.709177+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-16T20:51:14.285964+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-12-16T20:51:16.892012+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-16T20:51:16.892044+00:00 app[web.1]: > social-media-app@0.1.0 start /app
2020-12-16T20:51:16.892045+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-12-16T20:51:16.892045+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T20:51:20.008878+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.19.83.162/
2020-12-16T20:51:20.009454+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-12-16T20:51:20.009592+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-12-16T20:51:20.009709+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-12-16T20:51:20.009979+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-12-16T20:51:20.009981+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T20:51:20.107792+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-16T20:51:20.149048+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-16T20:51:21.146354+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=college-social-media-app.herokuapp.com request_id=e534c771-8266-47ff-9654-dbff9e06bcf3 fwd="98.217.113.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https   
2020-12-16T20:51:21.890235+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=college-social-media-app.herokuapp.com request_id=12faed63-e137-4094-a8b1-abb0da32d249 fwd="98.217.113.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-16T21:03:26.100464+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=college-social-media-app.herokuapp.com request_id=b1f424f0-3bfa-450a-b966-f311444e79ec fwd="54.226.141.215" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http    
2020-12-16T21:18:33.942775+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-16T21:18:43.329432+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-12-16T21:18:45.988296+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T21:18:45.988318+00:00 app[web.1]: > social-media-app@0.1.0 start /app
2020-12-16T21:18:45.988318+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-12-16T21:18:45.988319+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T21:18:48.317690+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.207.246/
2020-12-16T21:18:48.318135+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-12-16T21:18:48.318240+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-12-16T21:18:48.318338+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-12-16T21:18:48.318551+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-12-16T21:18:48.318553+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T21:18:48.409919+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-16T21:18:48.449952+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-16T21:41:45.930743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=college-social-media-app.herokuapp.com request_id=71752592-39ff-4e7c-a322-40c51b30e9e5 fwd="94.130.167.123" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-12-16T21:41:46.160190+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=college-social-media-app.herokuapp.com request_id=2090702e-95cb-4f8c-ad07-0f84de7fbc46 fwd="94.130.167.123" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http    
2020-12-16T22:26:03.650558+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-16T22:26:16.660922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-12-16T22:26:18.817984+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T22:26:18.818013+00:00 app[web.1]: > social-media-app@0.1.0 start /app
2020-12-16T22:26:18.818014+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-12-16T22:26:18.818014+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T22:26:21.222563+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.28.182/
2020-12-16T22:26:21.223020+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-12-16T22:26:21.223111+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-12-16T22:26:21.223199+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-12-16T22:26:21.223417+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-12-16T22:26:21.223419+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-16T22:26:21.313328+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-16T22:26:21.348151+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-16T23:41:47.600206+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=college-social-media-app.herokuapp.com request_id=facfda12-0223-4bd1-848c-ba4b2ee99017 fwd="98.217.113.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https   
2020-12-16T23:41:49.026899+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=college-social-media-app.herokuapp.com request_id=a0739ab1-be60-4a71-a4d8-51d12b860aa7 fwd="98.217.113.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is the relevant code in my server.js file:

```
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;

const userRouter = require('./routes/user')
app.use('/user', userRouter)
const homepageRouter = require('./routes/home')
app.use('/homepage', homepageRouter)
const forumRouter = require('./routes/forum')
app.use('/forum', forumRouter)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Here is my ProcFile:

```
web:node src/index.js
web:node backend/server.js
```

Here is my package.json file which is in the root directory

```
{
  "name": "social-media-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express-pino-logger": "^5.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.9",
    "node-env-run": "^3.0.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "pino-colada": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "secure": "false"
}
```

Here is the package.json file which is in the backend folder:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "node-env-run server --exec nodemon | pino-colada",
    "dev": "run-p server start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.20"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

I have already set the needed Config Variables in the Heroku Consoles with the exception of the PORT variable, as Heroku should create its own PORT variable during run-time. Perhaps I need something in my package.json file? I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: The log entries you have shared here are not the relevant ones. Please replace them with detailed logs that should precede them.

Comment: @Chris I just edited my post to reflect the detailed logs. I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Is your `Procfile` actually called `ProcFile`? Those are two different names, and Heroku won't use the latter. I'm pretty sure yours isn't being used, whatever it is called; instead, the default is being used: "Starting process with command `npm start`".

Comment: Also, I don't think you can have multiple `web` processes. Normally your client shouldn't need to run anything: you'd build it into a bunch of files that can be hosted statically.

Comment: @Chris my file was actually called ProcFile, but even though I changed it I am still getting "Starting Process with command `npm start`". Also regarding the web processes, which one should I keep between the `index.js` and the `server.js`?

Comment: Is your `Procfile` in the root directory of your project, or in a subdirectory? The one you keep depends entirely on what you are trying to do. I _suspect_ you should be keeping your server process, building your client as part of the build process, and serving it up as static files.

Comment: I made sure of all those things but I'm still encountering the problem. Perhaps its something to do with the package.json file? The scripts code for my root directory package.json file is `"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }`

Comment: Code is very hard to read in comments. Please [edit] it into your question instead.

Comment: @Chris sorry about that, I've edited it now